# extract inferred return type with typescript API

Tags: typescript, inferred-type

I can interact with the typescript compiler API to compile `*.ts` to `*.js`

```js
import * as ts from "typescript";

const source = "function foo(xs: Array<number>) { let total=0; for (const x of xs) { total += x; } return total; }";

let result = ts.transpileModule(source, { compilerOptions: { module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS }});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Is there any way I can get the inferred return type of `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way of obtaining the return type is using the compiler API's type checker:

1. First you'll need to create an AST out of your source code using `createProgram`
2. Get a type checker for that program with `getTypeChecker`
3. Find the AST node of that function declaration
4. Extract its signature of that declaration using `getSignatureFromDeclaration`
5. Extract the signature's return type using `getReturnType` (this will get a ts.Type object)

There might be an easier way to obtain what you require, but this one worked for me.

for example, if your function is in fun.ts:

```js
const program = ts.createProgram(['fun.ts'])
const checker = program.getTypeChecker()
const sourceFile = program.getSourceFiles().filter(sf => !sf.isDeclarationFile)[0] // to filter all unwanted declaration files
const decl = sourceFile.statements[0] as ts.FunctionDeclaration
const retType = checker.getSignatureFromDeclaration(decl)!.getReturnType()
```

Comment: Thanks ! it worked - I had some minor compatibility issues I fixed, so I'll add my final version as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@AdiHarif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21516099/adiharif)'s answer I'm adding my final version<sup>1</sup>:

```js
import * as ts from "typescript";

const options = { target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5, module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS }
const program = ts.createProgram(['example.ts'], options)
const checker = program.getTypeChecker()
const sourceFile = program.getSourceFiles().filter(sf => !sf.isDeclarationFile)[0] // to filter all unwanted declaration files
const decl = sourceFile.statements[0] as ts.FunctionDeclaration
const retType = checker.getSignatureFromDeclaration(decl)!.getReturnType()
console.log(retType);
```

When I used the following `example.ts`:

```js
function foo(x: number) {
  return `X = ${x}`;
}
```

I got the correct answer:

```bash
$ npx tsc answer.ts
$ node answer.js | grep 'intrinsicName'
  intrinsicName: 'string',
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Typescript compiler complained about missing `options`